# Scala: Intellij shows compile errors on Import statements

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to teach myself scala and I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3. The editor does not recognize `import` commands. Errors appear. I have downloaded libraries, but the problem persists. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks for posting your first question. You absolutely need to include (1) the exact scala code you have written which does not work (aka minimum reproduction) AND the exact error message that Intellij is giving you. Without those two things your question is unlikely to be answered and may be downvoted by others.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

1.) I created a scala project:

In your console:

*$ activator new my-first-app play-scala*

Please bear in mind that I just automate the creation of scala project which follow the conventional project structure. I am using the Play framework and activator command, fyi, but this is out of topic.

2.) I open the project folder in IntelliJ by

a. Go to File -> New -> Project from existing source

b. find the "my-first-app" folder

c. double click the "build.sbt"

d. a prompt appear and check the "Use auto-import" checkbox

e. make sure the project sdk is a JDK 1.8

[image]

f. Click OK.

g. Select the modules data as root. As is.

h. Go to Settings (Ctrl + Alt + s)

I. Under "Languages & Frameworks", go to "Play2"

j. In the Play2 section, check the "Use SBT watcher" and "Use Play 2 compiler for this project"
[image]

h. Click "apply" then click "ok"

g. if still not work, refresh the project by going to SBT child window of intelliJ and click the refresh button.

[image]

Good luck! :D